# How to Limit the series data in highcharts just showing 10 data and short it desc?

Tags: highcharts

can some one help me to limit the data that show in highchart,,
i have a lot of data and want to make it just 10 showing but before that i need to descanding my data.
so just 10 data with high value..

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Menu Terlaris'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Menu'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Terjual (Pesanan)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {                
            formatter: function (tooltip) {
            var items = this.points || splat(this),
                series = items[0].series,
                s;

            // build the header
            s = [series.tooltipHeaderFormatter(items[0])];

            // sort the values
            items.sort(function(a, b){
                return ((a.y < b.y) ? -1 : ((a.y > b.y) ? 1 : 0));
            });
            items.reverse();

            // build the values
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                series = item.series;
                s.push((series.tooltipFormatter && series.tooltipFormatter(item)) ||
                    item.point.tooltipFormatter(series.tooltipOptions.pointFormat) );
            });

            // footer
            s.push(tooltip.options.footerFormat || '');

            return s.join('');
        },
        shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [
        { name : 'name1', data:[100] },
            { name : 'name2', data:[200] },
            { name : 'name3', data:[300] },
    ...
    ]
```

so i want that series data that show in highchart is just 10 data with descending with 'data' value.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Can you create a jsfiddle to show the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts has no included limit module, but you can "cut" your data in preprocessing (before chart initialization). In other words in you get i.e 150 points, then you can use [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to "cut array" and initialize chart with new data. Desending values are available only when you use [reverted](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.reversed) paramter on xAxis.